# How to align ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, datepicker, customization, ngx-bootstrap

I want to customize the ngx-bootstrap datepicker. I want to align left/right side of my input, but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-12 col-md-4 form-group">
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker
           [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }">
  </div>
```

[Now it works like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IQse.png)

[But I want something like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xXYH.png)

I couldn't find any way to customize the datepicker. Can anyone help with this problem.

Comment: I have similar issues--the datepicker's left edge is off the screen--https://imgur.com/a/t8m9ST7

Answer (score 14):

Use the placement property to align the datepicker. You can safely remove the `adaptivePosition` and position using the `placement` property alone.

```
<input type="text"
       placeholder="Datepicker"
       class="form-control"
       bsDatepicker
       placement="bottom right">
```

Comment: This solved my problem, should be marked as answer.

Comment: It's working but compiler returns typescript error with message: 
`error TS2322: Type '"bottom right"' is not assignable to type '"left" | "right" | "top" | "bottom"'.`
Any idea how to fix/avoid  this error? I'm using angular 9 and ngx-bootstrap 5.6.1 and documentation only mentions about  top/bottom/left/right placement.

Comment: Cannot use "bottom" with "right" together (tried with version 5.0.0)

Answer (score 2):

```
   // placement="top" -- add this
    
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           bsDatepicker
           placement="top">


options are : "left" | "right" | "top" | "bottom"
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do it with Johns Mathew solution because `placement="bottom right"` is not a valid option, as Falcon mentioned.
What I did was wrap the datepicker in a container and did some little workaround:

```
<div class="input-group datepicker-right"> <-- Container
     <input type="text" #dpData="bsDaterangepicker" bsDaterangepicker>
     <a class="input-group-text" (click)="showCalendar(dpData)">
       <i class="la la-calendar"></i>
     </a>
</div>
```

And I created a css class:

```
.datepicker-right bs-daterangepicker-container {
   top: 33px !important; /* Height of my input */
   left: unset !important;
   transform: none !important;
   right: 0px !important;
}
```

And voilà!